# Unable to return value from Vuejs method and firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

i want to return the value from the firestore OnSnapshot function so that i can retrieve the url of user image. I am using vuejs and firestore. And i have `activeUserImg` function in created property of vue.

```
activeUserImg: function () {
           const u = firebase.auth().currentUser;
firebase.firestore().collection('Colleges').doc(u.uid).onSnapshot(function(doc) {

         var img_arr=[];
        this.img_arr.push(doc.data())
        this.img= doc.data().logo
    });
      return this.img || this.$store.state.AppActiveUser.img;

        }
```

and everytime it is the showing the value in return as undefined.

the image code:

```
<img
v-if="activeUserImg.startsWith('http')"
key="onlineImg"
:src="activeUserImg"
alt="user-img"
width="40" height="40"/>
<img
v-else
key="localImg"
:src="require(`@/assets/images/portrait/small/${activeUserImg}`)"
alt="user-img"
width="40" height="40"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of you firestore database.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UKA4HKw.png    the screenshot of firestore

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the function in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and wait for when the result is available.

Example:

```
activeUserImg: () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          const u = firebase.auth().currentUser;

          firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('Colleges')
            .doc(u.uid)
            .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
                var img_arr=[];
                this.img_arr.push(doc.data())
                this.img= doc.data().logo

                // return the result
                resolve(this.img || this.$store.state.AppActiveUser.img);
            });
    });
}
```

Then, you can access the value by

```
activeUserImg.then(result => {
   console.log(result);
})
```

Or

```
const result = await activeUserImg()

console.log(result)
```

Comment: i used the same function but still the image is not showing. i have added the image code in the main code

Comment: Are you getting the image result from firebase? Did you console the `doc` data you got from firebase and it is there? Do you want to replicate somewhere where someone can take a look?

Comment: console.log(result) shows the url in console but the function when called in <img> tag does not shows the image

Comment: Okay. Now that's an entirely different problem from the question. Try using:

  :src="/assets/images/portrait/small/${activeUserImg()}"  

for the "v-else" if you are sure the image is available in the assets folder

Comment: actually i am trying to retrieve image from firebase firestore which is stored in the form of url(stored in logo). my code is in the format that the function activeUserImg()either returns the firebase image url ( in the if part of v-if) or the local image ( in v-else) part . for now activeuseUserImg is not able to return the value of field 'logo'  from  my database

Answer (score 0):

return statement should be inside of the firestore callback just like below

```
activeUserImg: function () {
           const u = firebase.auth().currentUser;
firebase.firestore().collection('Colleges').doc(u.uid).onSnapshot(function(doc) {

     var img_arr=[];
    this.img_arr.push(doc.data())
    this.img= doc.data().logo
    return this.img || this.$store.state.AppActiveUser.img;
});


    }
```

Comment: i had tried this. It doesn,t work. It is still not returning the url address stored in firestore document field